# "Failed to fetch updates" popping up on app center and cannot install apps

Tags: appcenter, apps

New user here. I have seen similar questions here but none of the solutions in those questions fixed these problems.
When I open the app center, the "Failed to fetch updates" message pops up with the following details:

```
E: The repository 'http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter hera Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu hera Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu hera Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

[image]

Also when I try to install any app the "The package id's '' are not vaild" message pops up

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `hera` to `bionic` in the next files:

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list

Use the following command to automate this process:

```
find /etc/apt -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -0 sed -i 's/hera/bionic/g'
```

Comment: That worked a treat. Thank you so much. How does that work though?

Comment: @shivam The find command search all files in /etc/apt folder and send them for the "|" (pipe). Xargs gets the filenames from the pipe, takes them one by one, and executes the sed command on them. The sed command replaces hera to bionic in the files.

Comment: And what does replacing 'hera' to 'bionic' do? Is bionic another version of elementary

Comment: @shivam bionic is the codename of Ubuntu 18.04.4 (Bionic Beaver). The current version of elementary is based on Ubuntu.